# Codeigniter: Get the row number out of the query result based on given criteria

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a mysql table - mytable, like this:

```
name | sales
Mark | 4
Steve | 2
Rick | 5
David | 1
```

when fetching the result based on the number of sales done like:

```
$this->db->select('name,sales');
$this->db->where('sales >=', '2');
$this->db->order_by("sales", "desc"); 
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');
```

and put in a table with rank, it would look like:

```
Rank | Name | Sales
1 | Rick | 5
2 | Mark | 4
3 | Steve | 2
```

But, I don't want to put it in a table. Instead, I want to know the rank of a person based on the query criteria. For example, given the name Mark, I should directly get his row number (rank) as '2'. What would be my mysql query to achieve this using codeigniter active record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish, isn't solvable in that way. This implies that MySQL knows what you consider a rank/position *before* having anything to work with.

The only managable way to do so, is iterating over your results, only printing what you wan't to.

```
$name = "Mark";
$rank = 0;
$this->db->select('name,sales');
$this->db->where('sales >=', '2');
$this->db->order_by("sales", "desc"); 
$query = $this->db->get('mytable');

foreach($query->result() as $row)
{
    $rank++;
    if( $row->name == $name )
    {
        echo $row->name . ' has rank ' . $rank;
        break; // No more iterating
    } 
}
```

You should consider doing some table changes - like adding an auto incremented ID to your table to identify rows on instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query='SELECT name,sales
FROM mytable
WHERE sales>=?
ORDER BY sales desc';
$params=array();
$params[]=2;
$result=$this->db->query($query,$params);
$result=$result->result_array();

print_r($result[2]);
```

Though you should probably just use a limit to get only the result you want:

```
$query='SELECT name,sales
FROM mytable
WHERE sales>=?
ORDER BY sales desc
LIMIT 1,1'; //offset 1, show 1 result
$params=array();
$params[]=2;
$result=$this->db->query($query,$params);
$result=$result->row_array();

print_r($result);
```

Comment: This is not using active record.

Comment: This is a good thing, active record queries are a bad practice. Without elaborating on this too much... Use the KISS principle of programming, form a SQL query by writing SQL.

Comment: Can you please make a query using two variables - **$sales_done** & **$executive_name** (both passed via post method), where $sales_done done corresponds to the `sales` column and $executive_name to `name` column of the database table `mytable`.